# Using Ubuntu, `ogrinfo` fails to open an mdb file

Tags: ubuntu, odbc, debian, gdal

Whenever I try to open a sample-mdb file, I'm getting

```
ogrinfo Campaign_Template.mdb 
ERROR 1: PGeo: MDB Tools driver not found!

Warning 1: Unable to install MDB driver for ODBC, MDB access may not supported.

ERROR 1: Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=Campaign_Template.mdb,
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)' : file not found
ERROR 1: PGeo: MDB Tools driver not found!

Warning 1: Unable to install MDB driver for ODBC, MDB access may not supported.

ERROR 1: Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=Campaign_Template.mdb,
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)' : file not found
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `Campaign_Template.mdb' with the following drivers.
```

I'm seeing the driver only mentioned in the docs,

```
apt-file search drv_pgeo
libgdal-doc: /usr/share/doc/libgdal-doc/gdal/drv_pgeo.html
```

However, the current package of `libgdal20` does not have `drv_pgeo` what happened to it, and where can I find it?

Comment: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2012-March/032267.html

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ I'm unsure of what to make of that. Is that indicating that the feature was yanked entirely? I know you can use mdbtools, I just recall that gdal was writing an mdb interface too.